# scheduled task last result 0xff

Tags: scheduled-tasks

Where can I find the meaning of 0xff in the scheduled task last result field?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, sometimes you will have to check the command documentations for errors from specific commands.

But with whatever information I know, I have explained the same as given below :-

The return codes are in hexadecimal. You can convert them to
decimal with a hex mode calculator or if you are using
NT/W2k/XP, by using "set /a 0xff" or by simple multiplication.

Multiply the second last number by 16 and add the last number
where A-F represents decimal 10-15 e.g. 0xB3 = 11*16+3 = 179.

0x0 = 0 = no error
0xff = 255 = More than 154 files failed to copy or ^C batch exit or
possibly scheduled task failed to run.
0x68 = 104 = 4 files failed to copy
0x67 = 103 = 3 files failed to copy
etc, etc,.

***Hemant***

Answer (score 0):

When a proccess exits it always returns a result or [exit code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status).  You typically don't ever see this code, however in the case of a scheduled task it can be very useful.  Often time it can indicate and error or describe whey the application exited.  Typically a successful or expected exit code is 0.  You will need to consult the particular application's documentation in order to determine the meaning of your given exit code, however it likely means an error occurred.